# Why do I get an error that sprintf is incompatible with type string?

Tags: f#

I have this F# code that fails to compile.

```
let wiql = 
    "SELECT [State], [Title], [Work Item Type], [ReferenceId]
     FROM WorkItems
     WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '%s'
     AND [Work Item Type] IN ('Product Backlog Item', 'Bug')
     AND ([ReferenceId] CONTAINS 'IM' OR [ReferenceId] CONTAINS 'CM' OR [ReferenceId] CONTAINS 'RF')"

let wiql = sprintf wiql projectName
```

The error I get on the red squiggly under the 2nd wiql is:
The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'Printf.StringFormat<('a -> 'b)>'

I am try to replace the %s with the projectName in the query string.

Thanks for any tips on how to correct this,

Matthew

Update: I tried out the answer to the question that my question is a duplicate of but I could not get that to work. That example uses printfn which works but when I try the same thing with sprintf it fails. There is some difference between them that I am failing to see.

Here is my F# Interactive session to demonstrate:

```
> let wiql = 
        Printf.TextWriterFormat<string -> unit>(
            "SELECT [State], [Title], [Work Item Type], [ReferenceId]
             FROM WorkItems
             WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '%s'
             AND [Work Item Type] IN ('Product Backlog Item', 'Bug')
             AND ([ReferenceId] CONTAINS 'IM' OR [ReferenceId] CONTAINS 'CM' OR [ReferenceId] CONTAINS 'RF')");;

val wiql : PrintfFormat<(string -> unit),System.IO.TextWriter,unit,unit>

> printfn wiql "DRILQUIP";;
SELECT [State], [Title], [Work Item Type], [ReferenceId]
             FROM WorkItems
             WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'DRILQUIP'
             AND [Work Item Type] IN ('Product Backlog Item', 'Bug')
             AND ([ReferenceId] CONTAINS 'IM' OR [ReferenceId] CONTAINS 'CM' OR [ReferenceId] CONTAINS 'RF')
val it : unit = ()
> let x = sprintf wiql "DRILQUIP";;

  let x = sprintf wiql "DRILQUIP";;
  ----------------^^^^

stdin(19,17): error FS0001: The type 'unit' does not match the type 'System.IO.TextWriter'
```

I also tried Printf.TextWriterFormat string> but that fails too.

Update:
Found it!

```
let wiql:Printf.StringFormat<string -> string> = "SELECT [State] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '%s'"

let x = sprintf wiql "DRILQUIP"

printfn "%s" x
```

Used Printf.StringFormat instead of Printf.TextWriterFormat to prepare a format for use with sprintf. If I understand the type signature  string> it's a format that has 1 replaceable string placeholder and returns a string.

This also works.

```
Printf.StringFormat<_>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, but basically, when you do `sprintf "format %s" args`, the format string gets converted to a `StringFormat` by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks @john-palmer, It took me a while to get it but I have sprintf working now.

Comment: A hint for next time: you can do `let test arg = sprintf arg some_stuff` and look at what type fsharpi generates.